# Create an HTML table from an existing array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've created an array containing a list of some car makes and based on it, I've made some select tags containing these cars. Next to each select tag, there is a text field where one can type in the price of the selected car. What I'd like to do is to, upon clicking the "Click" button, create a table containg the makes of all the selected cars along with the typed-in prices. So far, I've been able to create the table with the car makes but I can't figure out how to include the prices in the adjacent cells. 
Here's the HTML code:

```
<label>Item 1 </label><select class="cars"></select><label>Price</label> <input type="text" /><br /><br />
<label>Item 2 </label><select class="cars"></select><label>Price</label> <input type="text" /><br /><br />
<label>Item 3 </label><select class="cars"></select><label>Price</label> <input type="text" /><br /><br />
<label>Item 4 </label><select class="cars"></select><label>Price</label> <input type="text" /><br /><br />
<label>Item 5 </label><select class="cars"></select><label>Price</label> <input type="text" /><br /><br />
<label>Item 6 </label><select class="cars"></select><label>Price</label> <input type="text" /><br /><br />
<input type="text" id="value" />
<input type="button" value="Click" id="addNew" />
<table width="200" border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" id="table">
  <tr>
    <th>Product</th>
    <th>Amount</th>
  </tr>

</table>
```

and heres the jQuery code

```
//Tabela produktów
var cars = new Array(
'BMW',
'Audi',
'Mazda',
'Toyota',
'Ford',
'Honda',
'VW',
'Opel'
)
//Sortowanie tabeli alfabetycznie
cars.sort();
//Tworzenie listy rozwijanej
$(document).ready(function(){
    for(i=0;i<cars.length;i++){
        $(".cars").append("<option>"+ cars[i] +"</option>");
        }
    });
//Tworzenie tabeli
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#addNew").click(function(){
        $("select").each(function(){
            var x = $(this).val();
            $("#table").append("<tr><td>"+x+"</td><td></td></tr>");
                });
        });
    });
```

I'd appreciate all help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
var cars = new Array(
    'BMW',
    'Audi',
    'Mazda',
    'Toyota',
    'Ford',
    'Honda',
    'VW',
    'Opel'
)
//Sortowanie tabeli alfabetycznie
cars.sort();
//Tworzenie listy rozwijanej
$(document).ready(function () {
    for (i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
        $(".cars").append("<option>" + cars[i] + "</option>");
    }
});
//Tworzenie tabeli
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#addNew").click(function () {
        $("select").each(function () {
            var x = $(this).val();
          $("#table").append("<tr><td>" + x + "</td><td>" + $(this).nextUntil("input[type=text]").next().val() + "</td></tr>");
        });
    });

});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/V5SSM/23/)